# how to make a function return two different data types without using Either?

Tags: haskell, custom-data-type

as said in the title, for example i have this function that throws an error of course :

```
bhaskara a b c = 
    if discriminant >= 0 then (x1,x2) else str_disc
    where 
        discriminant = (b^2 - (4*a*c))
        str_disc = "the discriminant is less than zero"
        x1 = ((-b) - sqrt (b^2 - (4*a*c))) / (2*a)
        x2 = ((-b) - sqrt (b^2 - (4*a*c))) / (2*a)
```

i heard you could use custom data types so i thought doing something like this but i'm clearly doing something wrong here :

```
data Result = (Double, Double) | String
bhaskara :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Result
bhaskara a b c = 
    if discriminant >= 0 then (x1,x2) else str_disc
    where 
        discriminant = (b^2 - (4*a*c))
        str_disc = "the discriminant is less than zero"
        x1 = ((-b) - sqrt (b^2 - (4*a*c))) / (2*a)
        x2 = ((-b) - sqrt (b^2 - (4*a*c))) / (2*a)
```

could someone show how to approach this?

by the way i know i'm not including the case where the discriminant is equal to zero

Comment: You need to use a data constructor, for example `data Result = Values Double Double | Error String`

Comment: Bhaskar is a cool func name, does it mean something?

Comment: @Evgeny haha yeah idk what it means its just a formula by this guy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bh%C4%81skara_II
lets you find the roots of second degree equations

Comment: Cool, thanks of the link! I did not know who prosposed it first. It was a nameless formula in our high school curriculum. Overall nice example for Either you proposed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
data Result = (Double, Double) | String
```

That's not a valid usage of `data`. You need to specify data constructors:

```
data Result = Result (Double, Double) | Error String
```

However, you don't need a pair in `Result`:

```
data Result = Result Double Double | Error String

bhaskara :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Result
bhaskara a b c = 
    if discriminant >= 0 then Result x1 x2  else Error str_disc
    where 
        discriminant = (b^2 - (4*a*c))
        str_disc = "the discriminant is less than zero"
        x1 = ((-b) - sqrt (b^2 - (4*a*c))) / (2*a)
        x2 = ((-b) - sqrt (b^2 - (4*a*c))) / (2*a)
```

That being said, `Result` is more or less `Either String (Double, Double)` as we can provide an isomorphism. You probably want to reconsider using `Either`.

Comment: thank you very much, do you have any idea if it's possible to prevent the data constructors from showing next to the result when printing?

Comment: @brian You have to write your own instance of `Show` for `Result`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use an algebraic datatype (although I'd recommend it), you can also resort to the “built-in error reporting” of the `Double` datatype.  There is a special value which indicates that the the result of a computation is not a number (short: NaN or nan).  This is fully supported in Haskell:

```
nan :: Double
nan = (0/0)

bhaskara :: Double -> Double -> Double -> (Double, Double)
bhaskara a b c = 
    if discriminant >= 0.0 then (x1,x2) else (nan,nan)
    where 
        discriminant = (b^2 - (4*a*c))
        x1 = ((-b) - sqrt (b^2 - (4*a*c))) / (2*a)
        x2 = ((-b) - sqrt (b^2 - (4*a*c))) / (2*a)
```

However, in this case the burden of checking for `NaN` (using `isNaN`) goes to the caller whereas with an algebraic datatype such as `Either` you can just pattern-match.